# Start Notification on click event of start stopwatch

Tags: android, timer, notifications

I want to start timer and notification when click start button timer should be stop when we click on notification..and timer time should should be note in another activity when click on notification this is my code what i done so far.
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{

```
     public void onClick(View v)
  {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
             PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
            Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle("New notification")
            .setContentText("Subject").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent).build();
            NotificationManager notificationManager = 
            (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            // hide the notification after its selected
            noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notificationManager.notify(0, noti);

        }
    });
```

Comment: What you have done so far?

Comment: hello sir..I have one button.when we click on that button notification should open.It should display to user as notification your app is running and time progress when I click on notification timer should be stop and open activity where I want to store totat time app running

Comment: Please include sample code so we can see what you have done so far.

Comment: I want to start timer and notification when click start button timer should be stop when we click on notification..and timer time should should be note in another activity when click on notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when you click on the start button of your stopwatch, call the notification manager and display the notification.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
                Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle("New notification")
                .setContentText("Subject").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent).build();
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                // hide the notification after its selected
                noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                notificationManager.notify(0, noti);

            }
        });
```

Comment: thanx its works but it show some error Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): android.app.Notification.Builder#setContentText

Comment: Go to AndroidManifest.xml file and change `android:minSdkVersion` to 11. That is, `android:minSdkVersion="11" `

Comment: Thanks sir its works...I want to start timer also when click on that button and stop timer when click on notification and timer time should be take in another activity..please suggest if know how to do that..

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
private void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {

int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
String appname = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
Notification notification;
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
new Intent(context, myactivity.class), 0);

// To support 2.3 os, we use "Notification" class and 3.0+ os will use
// "NotificationCompat.Builder" class.
if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
notification = new Notification(icon, message, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, appname, message,
contentIntent);
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

} else {
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
context);
notification = builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(appname).setWhen(0)
.setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(appname)
.setContentText(message).build();

notificationManager.notify(0 , notification);
}
}
```

Hope this helps.